# Why would I ever not use multiple col sizes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Why would I ever not include all of the possible column sizes in a boostrap rule? Like this:

```
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
```

Isn't it better to do so just in case?

Comment: No, it is not better. In the example you've presented here the `<div>` will always span 3 columns of width.  It will already adjust based on the breakpoint so every `col-*-3` you have beyond `col-xs-3` is superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

If they are the same, it is redundant.

Per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid):

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal
>   to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller
>   devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element
>   will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large
>   devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present.

So if you always want it to be 3 columns (1/4 screen width), you could do just `<div class="col-3-xs">` which would have the same effect as `<div class="col-3-xs col-3-sm col-3-md col-3-lg">`.

However, part of the benefit of Bootstrap is that it allows responsiveness, so you may not want an extra small screen to have the same proportions as a large screen, hence the different classes.